# unlink doesn't seem to work in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I have the following piece of code so that when I delete a row from the database I also delete the files associated with it, the code runs smoothly and I'm actually able to delete the rows from the database but somehow I'm unable to delete the files from the server directory, note that row "photo_filename" contains a name such as "photo.png" or so, also calling _ *DIR* _ from the file returns a path like this "**...**\Desktop\project/procedures", I'm not even getting any warnings I tried echoing a a string if unlink was successful and some other string if not successful, but the weird thing is I don't get any output, it is as if the loop doesn't even run, can someone point me towards the right direction on what I'm missing right here. Thank you

```
try {
  $db->beginTransaction();    // Begin transaction
  $query = "DELETE FROM properties "
    . " WHERE property_id = :property_id";  // Delete requested property.
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam(":property_id", $property["property_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM photos "
    . " WHERE property_id = :property_id";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam(":property_id", $property["property_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $photo) {
    try {
      unlink(__DIR__ . "/../img/" . $photo["image_filename"])
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      throw $e;
    }
  }
  $query = "DELETE FROM photos "
    . " WHERE property_id = :property_id";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam(":property_id", $property["property_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {    // If there is a problem
  $db->rollBack();  //If there was a problem undo the whole attempt to insert
  $session->getFlashBag()->add("error", "Hubo un problema" . $e->getMessage()); // Display a message
  redirect("/show.php?id=".$property_id); // And redirect
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Well your missing a ; after the unlink line.

Comment: Have you checked that you have any data remaining in the photos table for that particular property_id? If you ran the code without a catchable error you will have deleted all the entries in the photos table for that property.

Comment: can you please echo the unlink location so that you can confirm that it's going to the right direction to unlink ?
also please check the folder permission as your program has the right permission to delete or modify any file

Comment: You are deleting from the database before running the query which in turn deletes the file. You should run the Select query first, then delete the file before eventually deleting the `property_id` from the database

Comment: just thoughts: imo, deleting files is one of the least reliable operations. The issue is that the o/s may have it 'owned' for various reasons. It is the one command that I suppress error messages on. I try and delete in the executing script. But I don't bother if it fails. What I do is actually keep a list of filenames to delete. I have a separate job which runs and tries to delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized my dumb mistake, so "properties" table was linked to "photos" table so when I began the transaction and deleted the property from the table the photos associated with it were also automatically deleted, so when I selected and looped through the photos table to get the files there weren't any, leaving this here just in case someone runs into something similar, thank you guys for responding.